# What is the difference between On chain and installed smart contracts?

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger, smartcontracts

What is the difference between On chain and installed smart contracts? Has it do with Address or node? If yes, what is the address?

Comment: What kind of blockchain are you talking about?

Comment: Private blockchain like hyperledger.

Comment: @ArkadyPrivate blockchains like hyperledger

Answer (score 0):

The diference is simple:

**On-chain Smart Contracts**

These are executed when a transaction happens on the blockchain. And they are stored right inside the blockchain as well.

**Installed Smart Contracts**

These Smart contracts are executed before the commit happens to the ledger or before the network is launched.

You could find more info at [source](https://hackernoon.com/how-are-smart-contracts-executed-in-hyperledger-57efebf03f12)

Comment: This is the basic difference i know. But where are these on chain smart contracts stored. In address or node? If it is address, what is it?

Comment: @Gulshan take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42081194/where-do-smart-contracts-reside-in-blockchain-ethereum-or-hyperledger, probably it will be useful for you